# Database over internet

Tags: android, database

How can I make a database over internet, so I can update the database and all the devices that have the app will get that update to. Am I supposed to use mySQL database for that like in php? =) 
 
I have google'd and all that stuff but can't find a good answer.

 I hope you know what I mean!
 Thanks! :)

(Sorry for bad english!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to decide where you want your data to be stored. You can store them locally on the device or on a server accessible through the Internet. I assume that you want them to be stored centrally through the Internet, in that case you can either connect to the database directly or through an interface. For most of my work I usually put up some scripts to handle HTTP-request (I like using the web technologies) on a server and connect toward this. If you make a PHP or other script you can call this by sending a request for either getting data or setting data.

Comment: Okey, yeah I want to make it over internet. Do you have a good tutorial or something for connect to the PHP/other website's? Or could I get the data from a website? Is that possible?

Comment: So what you would have to do is first to make a script or more which gets and sets data (if sets based on POST-data). What you would need to do in Android is to implement a HTTP-request. I just googled it and the first forum thread actually also have some code which you could try out: https://www.google.no/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=send+http+requests+android

Comment: Thanks dude! I must suck on google'ing... But ThanksThanksThanks!

Comment: @GuiceU Note that most frameworks have extensions that make integration like this easier, so you shouldn't have to entirely reinvent it yourself..

Comment: Okey, didn't really get that but the request HTTP just get the source code of the website?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense.  A database isn't inherently tied to the internet.  Instead, you have a database on a machine, and provide an interface to it.  One way to do this is to do something like write a Rails web interface using a REST based communication mechanism, and then have your apps interface with your database using HTTP requests.  This is probably the most commonly done thing, and there are lots of libraries for things like rails, PHP, etc...